# I converted Website with Google map to Android app. Google map not shown in Android app

Tags: javascript, c#, android, asp.net, android-studio

I created Empty project in Android Studio and converted website to Android app. When I open a website in Chrome browser everything works and Google map visible, but in converted Android app Google map not visible. How is it possible to fix?

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView mywebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mywebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings=mywebView.getSettings();
        mywebView.loadUrl("https://mywebsite-Url");
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.loadUrl("http://maps.google.com/maps?" + "saddr=43.0054446,-87.9678884" + "&daddr=42.9257104,-88.0508355");
```